# Invariant Violation: AsyncStorage has been removed. Error persists even after upgrading

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm getting this error when trying to build for android:

```
Invariant Violation: AsyncStorage has been removed from react-native core. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage, js engine: hermes
```

How ever I am using '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' already and I'm importing correctly:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

Here is a snipit of my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^5.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^10.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^10.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^10.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7",
```